# How to use a function to change background color with linear gradient?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change the background color randomly using functions but it seems not working.

I've tried with normal/basic colors and it works normally.

```
var change = document.getElementById("meBaby"); // add to the top

function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
}

function changeColor() {
    change.style.backgroundColor = getRandomColor();
}

setInterval(changeColor, 10000);
```

However, when I try to change to linear gradient it is not possible, sorry I don't know where is my mistake. I even remove the `var color = '#';` to `var color;` to see whether it would work but nothing. See the code below

```
var change = document.getElementById("meBaby"); // add to the top

function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = ['linear-gradient(120deg, #f6d365 0%, #fda085 100%)',
    'linear-gradient(to top, #fdcbf1 0%, #fdcbf1 1%, #e6dee9 100%)',
    ];
    var color;
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)];
    }
    return color;

}

function changeColor() {
    change.style.backgroundColor = getRandomColor();
}
changeColor();
setInterval(changeColor, 10000);
```

I `console.log(changeColor());` but it is undefined I don't know why. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: I'm dying to know why you think this should work... But `console.log(changeColor())` shows `undefined` because there is no `return` statement in `changeColor`.

Comment: Yes, that's why I am asking @Niet. Stack overflow is here for this. :)

Comment: `background-color` doesn't implement linear gradients, you have to change `background-image`.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol why should there be?

Comment: I think it's because of the `for`, you only need 1 item from your `letters`.

Comment: Simple debugging would show why..... `console.log(color); return color;`

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio  No, but then the OP didn't understand why it returned `undefined`, and @Niet pointed out that he's not returning anything in that function.

Comment: @Keith true that, now I see the further question at bottom of the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are concatenating the variable `color`, which starts `undefined` (with any defined value).

Also, you are creating an array of linear gradients, and then concatenating multiple gradients.

Just debug your code line by line and you will notice this. F12 is your friend. Good developers stick to it forever. This is what you will see:

```
"undefinedlinear-gradient(120deg, #f6d365 0%, #fda085 100%)linear-gradient(to top, #fdcbf1 0%, #fdcbf1 1%, #e6dee9 100%)linear-gradient(to top, #fdcbf1 0%, #fdcbf1 1%, #e6dee9 100%)linear-gradient(to top, #fdcbf1 0%, #fdcbf1 1%, #e6dee9 100%)linear-gradient(120deg, #f6d365 0%, #fda085 100%)linear-gradient(120deg, #f6d365 0%, #fda085 100%)"
```

Is kinda weird the way you are creating gradients actually, but you can fix that with something like this:

```
function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = [
        'linear-gradient(120deg, #f6d365 0%, #fda085 100%)',
        'linear-gradient(to top, #fdcbf1 0%, #fdcbf1 1%, #e6dee9 100%)',
    ];
    return letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)];
}
```

And finally, use the `background` CSS property, not the `backgroundColor` CSS property.

By the way, this will get two "not so random" gradients, as they will be predefined. If you truly want random gradients use something like this:

```js
var change = document.getElementById("meBaby");
function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
}
function getRandomGradient() {
    return 'linear-gradient('+(Math.random()*360)+'deg, '+getRandomColor()+' 0%, '+getRandomColor()+' 100%)';
}

function changeColor() {
    change.style.background = getRandomGradient();
}

changeColor();
setInterval(changeColor, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="meBaby">TEST</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few mistakes on the `linear-gradient` approach:

- 1) You have to set the `background` property, not the `backgroundColor` property.
- 2) The `for` loop have no sense now, you will choose an option from the array, not the `6` hexadecimal characters of a `color`.

## Example:

```js
var change = document.getElementById("meBaby");

function getRandomColor()
{
    var letters = [
      'linear-gradient(120deg, #f6d365 0%, #fda085 100%)',
      'linear-gradient(to top, #fdcbf1 0%, #fdcbf1 1%, #e6dee9 100%)',
      'linear-gradient(to right, #ffffff 0%, #555555 100%)'
    ];

    var color = letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)];
    return color;
}

function changeColor()
{
    change.style.background = getRandomColor();
}

changeColor();
setInterval(changeColor, 5000);
```

```css
#meBaby {
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="meBaby">TEST</div>
```

---

## Update

This was not asked on the original question, but in case you need to generate a random `linear-gradient` without having a predefined set, then I will proceed like this:

```js
var change = document.getElementById("meBaby");

function getRandom(min, max)
{
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}

function getRandomColor()
{
    var color = "#";

    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        color += getRandom(0, 16).toString(16);
    }

    return color;
}

function getRandomLinearGradient()
{
    var d = getRandom(0, 360);
    var c1 = getRandomColor(), c2 = getRandomColor();
    return `linear-gradient(${d}deg, ${c1}, ${c2})`;
}

function changeColor()
{

    change.style.background = getRandomLinearGradient();
    console.log("New background is: ", change.style.background);
}

changeColor();
setInterval(changeColor, 5000);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}

#meBaby {
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="meBaby">TEST</div>
```

Note, you can use [Number.toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) with a `radix` of `16` to get a hexadecimal representation of a number. Also, I have used [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) on the `getRandomLinearGradient()` method, you should check [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Browser_compatibility) before using it.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a function for generate random hex color and set color , and generate random angle and set .

```js
function getRandomColor(){
return  "#000000".replace(/0/g,function(){
    return (~~(Math.random()*16)).toString(16);});
}


setInterval(function(){
document.getElementById("meBaby").style.background = 'linear-gradient('+(Math.random()*360)+'deg,'+ getRandomColor()+ ' 0%,'+getRandomColor()+ ' 100%)';
}, 1000);
```

```css
#meBaby{
 height:100px;
 width:500px;
}
```

```html
<div id="meBaby"></div>
```

update : you can also set random direction like :

```js
function getRandomColor(){
return  "#000000".replace(/0/g,function(){
    return (~~(Math.random()*16)).toString(16);});
}


function getRandomDirection(){
    var directions=['top left','top center','top right','center left','center center','center right','bottom left','bottom center','bottom right'];
   return directions[Math.floor(Math.random() * directions.length)];
}

setInterval(function(){
document.getElementById("meBaby").style.background = 'linear-gradient(to '+getRandomDirection()+','+ getRandomColor()+ ' 0%,'+getRandomColor()+ ' 100%)';
}, 1000);
```

```css
#meBaby{
 height:100px;
 width:500px;
}
```

```html
<div id="meBaby"></div>
```

read more about [linear-gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient)